# mirror axis not duplicating armatures

Tags: armature, mirror, axis, duplicate

[image]

okay...im not sure what I'm doing wrong, I have x mirror axis on to duplicate the bone as u  can see in the image...however it is not duplicating like it should.

Comment: Maybe first apply the Rotation in Object mode (Ctrl A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your armature first needs to be symmetrized. Make sure that you've called your left bone with the _L or .L suffixe (for example *arm_L*) then go into *Armature > Symmetrize*, it will automatically create a bone with the invert name (*arm_R*). If the *X-Axis Mirror* option is activated you'll act on the mirrored bone.

Also, apply the *Rotation* of your object in *Object* mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)

Comment: rotation is appied and it still doesnt work

Comment: I've edited, I guess this is the problem here?